# Calling a method form a different class ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am just starting with Ruby and Rspec, so if I am not very specific I apologise for my bad syntax in advance.

I have two classes, Airport and Weather, that should communicate so I can call the `stormy?` method in Weather from Airport. What I want to do is stop planes from taking off when the weather is bad.
I have defined a `bad_weather` method but it doesn't work
Here is my code:

My test in Rspec

```
describe Airport do 
  it ' does not allow planes to take off with stormy weather' do
    subject.take_off double(:plane)
    expect {(weather).to be_stormy?}.to raise_error "Flight cancelled due to bad weather"
  end
end
```

The class I want to take the method from

```
class Weather

  def stormy?
   roll >= 6
  end

private

  def roll
    rand(10)
  end
end
```

And the class I want to call the method in

```
class Airport

   DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10

   def initialize
     @planes = []
     @capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY
   end


  def take_off(plane)
    fail "Flight cancelled due to bad weather" if bad_weather?
    @planes.pop
  end

  def bad_weather?
    weather = Weather.new
    weather.stormy?
  end
end
```

I know my Rspec test in lousy, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's it doing instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have this situations where your subject under test is relying on other objects, you want to have control on those objects. In your scenario, you want to control the `weather` that your `airport` knows about.

In order to do that, you need to force it to make that when you ask `stormy?` to it, it returns `true`.  That way you are ensuring you are unit testing your `Airport` class and all the dependencies on other objects are under control.

Here is how I would do this:

```
class Airport
   DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10

   def initialize
     @planes = []
     @capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY
   end

  def take_off(plane)
    fail "Flight cancelled due to bad weather" if bad_weather?
    @planes.pop
  end

  def bad_weather?
    weather.stormy?
  end

  def weather
    @weather ||= Weather.new
  end
end
```

And then in your test, you are going to control what `weather` your airport has by doing this:

```
it 'does not allow planes to take off with stormy weather' do
  my_airport = Airport.new
  stormy_weather = Weather.new
  allow(stormy_weather).to receive(:is_stormy?) { true }
  allow(my_airport).to receive(:weather) { stormy_weather }

  expect(my_airport.take_off("Boeing")).to raise_error "Flight cancelled due to bad weather"
end
```

@SteveTurczyn answer is also valid. I personally don't like it because you are not just making the weather of your airport stormy, but any `Weather` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The technique for testing this is to force `#stormy?` to be true, and then to test that a take_off method call raises the error.

```
it 'does not allow planes to take off with stormy weather' do
  allow_any_instance_of(Weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return(true)
  my_airport = Airport.new
  expect(my_airport.take_off("Boeing")).to raise_error "Flight cancelled due to bad weather"
end
```

Incidentally, you'll also want to test the inverse of the condition, so another test would be useful.

```
it 'does not complain about bad weather if weather is good' do
  allow_any_instance_of(Weather).to receive(:stormy?).and_return(false)
  my_airport = Airport.new
  expect(my_airport.take_off("Boeing")).not_to raise_error "Flight cancelled due to bad weather"
end
```